# Python: How to execute only one async function call when the function is called multiple times in a short timeframe?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

## Context:

I'm currently coding a bot on Discord. The bot has a server class within it (with none of the fancy websockets and http requests) and a client class that serves as a bridge between the user and the server. The instance of the client class manages sending log messages to its corresponding user, updating its GUI (which is just an embed and a bunch of buttons attached to it which), and calling methods on the server class.

Currently I'm stuck on log messages. The current system is that a GUI message that contains the controls would always be the most recently sent message.

If another user were to join a room on the server class, this would cause the GUI message to not be updated anymore. Additionally, a log message would be sent to the user, which would cause the GUI message to not be the most recently sent message. Both problems are solved by the bot deleting the old GUI message and sending the updated one after that.

However, concurrent room joins may occur, so there's a chance the bot would interleave the "delete message" and "send message" parts of updating the GUI message like this:

```py
delete_message()
delete_message() # !!!
send_message()
send_message()
```

The second `delete_message()` would cause an error, since it can't find a message that has already been deleted.

My proposed solution would be the problem below.

---

## Problem:

Let's say I have an async function called `foo`:

```py
import asyncio


limit: int

async def foo():
    print("bar")


async def foo_caller():
    await asyncio.gather(foo(), foo(), foo(), foo(), foo())
    await foo()
    await foo()
```

This function would be called multiple times using the `foo_caller` function. Currently, this would print `bar` **7 times**.

The problem is, **How to execute only one function call when `foo` is called multiple times in a short timeframe?**

The solution should print `bar` only **three times**. One for the `await asyncio.gather(foo(), foo(), foo(), foo(), foo())`, and one each for the `await foo()`.

Comment: It's called "debounce" and is used in several technologies. In software, when the function is called it checks a flag. If the flag is set, it immediately returns. If the flag is not set, it sets the flag, starts a timer that unsets the flag later, then continues with its operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a class, "Regulator", which can be used to wrap any Callable in a way that meets your requirements.  The function will never be called more than once in a given time interval.  Excess calls will be discarded.

The `main` function is almost the same as your `foo_caller` but I added some time delays so that it will be clear that the test program works.  The program prints "bar" three times.

```
import asyncio
from typing import Callable

class Regulator:
    def __init__(self, interval: float, f: Callable, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Do not call the function f more than one per t seconds.
        
        interval is a time interval in seconds.
        f is a function
        *args and **kwargs are the usual suspects
        """
        self.interval = interval
        self.f = f
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.busy = False
        
    async def __call__(self):
        if not self.busy:
            self.busy = True
            asyncio.get_event_loop().call_later(self.interval, self.done)
            self.f(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            
    def done(self):
        self.busy = False
        
def say_bar():
    print("bar")
            
foo = Regulator(0.5, say_bar)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(foo(), foo(), foo(), foo(), foo())
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    await foo()
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    await foo()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

Anwering to your question below, but I think you have an X->Y problem here and you simply have to use message ids. But I'll answer on limiting async execution too.

You could use a time-based lock that exists for let's say 5 seconds. And we can be sure that all of the requests will be sent during the 5 seconds.

```
async def foo():
    if lock_exists():
        return
    async with lock(ttl=5):  # lock is alive for 5 seconds, the rest don't execute. Not released upon execution, but on a timer
        print("bar")


async def foo_caller():
    await asyncio.gather(foo(), foo(), foo(), foo(), foo())
    await foo()
    await foo()
```

But it's client-side logic, you could do a check if it exists before trying to delete or Try-Except.

Another approach is to be OK with exceptions -

```
async def foo():
    print("bar")


async def foo_caller():
    await asyncio.gather(foo(), foo(), foo(), foo(), foo(), return_exceptions=True) # Exceptions don't stop the code
    await foo()
    await foo()
```

This just won't raise an Exception.
But what I think you actually need it to record the ID of the message you need to delete. So

```
def delete_message(id_):  # get the id with a get request or similar
    send_delete_request_to_discord_here(message_id=id_)
```

Maybe get a storage for messages to delete or do a get request before each send_message to get the last message in the channel. If it exists, only then delete it. Something like that.

Comment: fixing message deletion problems is a no-no here since even if you did fix the double message delete (can just ignore error when deleting a message that doesn't exist), there's also still a double message send where you'll get two GUI messages.

your answer doesn't really specify how to implement `lock_exists()`, i'd really like to know how to code that up